# How to implement, React Native Drag-n-Drop

Tags: react-native

I want to implement react-native drag-and-drop, to swap component on the drop. supposed there is five component on a screen once I drag it should highlight dropable element. and once it is dropped the component should be swap.

Answer (score 5):

In order to implement drag an drop you need to use the pan responders. First you need to define where are you going to store the values when the object is moving, you can set a property on the state.

```
state = {
    pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
};
```

Then you will have to create the pan responders in `componentWillMount` for example:

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder : () => true,
    onPanResponderMove           : Animated.event([null,{ // <--- When moving
        dx : this.state.pan.x,
        dy : this.state.pan.y
    }]),
    onPanResponderRelease        : (e, gesture) => {} // <--- callback when dropped
});
```

Finally you need to set the left and top to the animated element in the render method.

```
<Animated.View 
    {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}  
     style={[this.state.pan.getLayout(), styles.circle]}>  
      <Text style={styles.text}>Drag me!</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

The `this.state.pan.getLayout()` returns the top and left, you need this in order to move the element around.

In order to swap the elements you need to implement the `onPanResponderRelease`.

For more detailed steps you can take a look at this tutorial: https://moduscreate.com/blog/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native

Comment: I have tried this, but I want to drag-n-drop circle and swap them and their values.

Comment: Then all you have to do is create an animation when dropping the  element ;)